# How to load a view that is larger than a specific area in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I"m relatively new to iOS development, as you can likely tell, and would like to display about 600 pixels worth of content (in height) on the screen. Just to give you a bit of context, I'm building a tab bar application, so what I'm assuming would be a UIScrollView cannot be defined in the App Delegate. Primarily, what I'm confused about is changing the size of the view and then defining the behaviour of the UIScrollView. I've looked everywhere, but they are all tutorials for < Xcode 4, plus none of them use the View Controller to define a scroll view. Is there a specific IBAction that would only allow the view to scroll up and down, not left and right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you define the [**contentSize**](http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/) and assign a subview to the `UIScrollView` you should be able to scroll automatically.

To make sure you have vertical and horizontal scrolling you could do this -

```
[scrollview setBounces:YES];
[scrollview setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
[scrollview setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
[scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

If you want to add double-tap to zoom etc. you could do that too in similar way...